# How do I retrieve releated models from subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with models. Model can be parent to another model (1 to 1)

```
type Model struct {
    ID                             uuid.UUID`
    Name                           string
    ParentModel                    Model
    CaseID                         uuid.UUID
    ProjectID                      uuid.UUID
    ChildModels                    []Model   
}
```

What I am trying to achive is:
select all models with the same caseID and select all models with caseId from parantModel and childrenModels.
Is it possible with subquery?
I have tried to select with preload (parent/children) with orm, but do not really get where to go from there

Comment: You have to write a [RECURSIVE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-RECURSIVE) query (in SQL), Or you have to solve this in application code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE public.model (
    id int4 NOT NULL,
    caption varchar NULL,
    parent_id int4 NULL,
    CONSTRAINT model_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO model (id, caption, parent_id) VALUES(1,    'Model1',       NULL);
INSERT INTO model (id, caption, parent_id) VALUES(2,    'Model2',       NULL);
INSERT INTO model (id, caption, parent_id) VALUES(3,    'Model3',       NULL);
INSERT INTO model (id, caption, parent_id) VALUES(4,    'Model4',       NULL);
INSERT INTO model (id, caption, parent_id) VALUES(5,    'Model1_1',     1);
INSERT INTO model (id, caption, parent_id) VALUES(6,    'Model1_2',     1);
INSERT INTO model (id, caption, parent_id) VALUES(7,    'Model1_3',     1);
INSERT INTO model (id, caption, parent_id) VALUES(8,    'Model1_2_1',   6);
INSERT INTO model (id, caption, parent_id) VALUES(9,    'Model1_2_2',   6);
INSERT INTO model (id, caption, parent_id) VALUES(10,   'Model4_1',     4);
```

Recursive Query example:

```
with recursive tbl(id, caption, parent_id) as (
select * from model  
where id = 1 
union all 
select model.* from model 
inner join tbl on tbl.id = model.parent_id 
)
select * from tbl
```

Result:

```
id  caption     parent_id
1   Model1      [NULL]
5   Model1_1    1
6   Model1_2    1
7   Model1_3    1
8   Model1_2_1  6
9   Model1_2_2  6
```